# I keep getting "Login sessions require session support" when I try to use tokens

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, token

So I am following a tutorial on how to use JSON tokens and I am getting an error, it was working fine using sessions but I can't figure out why I am having trouble, it is the exact code

this is my authenticate.js file:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const User = require("./models/user");
const JwtStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require("passport-jwt").ExtractJwt;
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken"); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens

const config = require("./config.js");

exports.local = passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

exports.getToken = function (user) {
    return jwt.sign(user, config.secretKey, { expiresIn: 3600 });
}; // config.secretKey is a string of random numbers

const opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = config.secretKey;

exports.jwtPassport = passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
        console.log("JWT payload:", jwt_payload);
        User.findOne({ _id: jwt_payload._id }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            } else if (user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    })
);

exports.verifyUser = passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false });
```

This is my app.js file (the main file):

```
const createError = require("http-errors");
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const logger = require("morgan");
const config = require("./config");

const indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
const usersRouter = require("./routes/users");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const passport = require("passport");

const url = config.mongoUrl;
const connect = mongoose.connect(url, {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

connect.then(
    () => console.log("Connected correctly to server"),
    (err) => console.log(err)
);

const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// app.use(cookieParser("12345-67890-09876-54321"));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

this is the routes/users.js file (I believe the problem is here because I can sign-up (create new users) but I can't login with the same users)

```
const express = require("express");
const User = require("../models/user");
const passport = require("passport");
const authenticate = require("../authenticate");

const router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get(
    "/",
    function (req, res, next) {
        res.send('send users')
    }
);

router.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
    User.register(
        new User({ username: req.body.username }),
        req.body.password,
        (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                res.statusCode = 500;
                res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                res.json({ err: err });
            } else {
                if (req.body.firstname) {
                    user.firstname = req.body.firstname;
                }
                if (req.body.lastname) {
                    user.lastname = req.body.lastname;
                }
                user.save((err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        res.statusCode = 500;
                        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        res.json({ err: err });
                        return;
                    }
                    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => {
                        res.statusCode = 200;
                        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        res.json({
                            success: true,
                            status: "Registration Successful!",
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    );
});

// I tried to add a console.log inside of the .post() route but it never reach it
router.post(
    "/login",
    passport.authenticate("local"),
    (req, res) => {
        const token = authenticate.getToken({ _id: req.user._id });
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.json({
            success: true,
            token: token,
            status: "You are successfully logged in!",
        });
    }
);

router.get("/logout", (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session) {
        req.session.destroy();
        res.clearCookie("session-id");
        res.redirect("/");
    } else {
        const err = new Error("You are not logged in!");
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Basically, every time that i go to localhost:3000/users/login and send a POST request with the username and password, it tells me that I need to use express-session but I am trying to use tokens instead of session

Comment: i guess. Issue must be from User.authenticate() method in your authenticate.js file. Check what is being returned in successful auth.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused when `passport.authenticate('local')` is called in *routes/users.js* file. It is a middleware that automatically calls `req.login` function in case correct username and password is provided.
The `req.login()` in turn, implements sessions in order to serialise the user in the session.

You can solve the issue by adding another parameter to `passport.authenticate()` as   `passport.authenticate('local', {session: false}`. This ensures sessions are not implemented in the 'local' strategy and subsequently login can be performed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it helped me. You have to remove `app.use(passort.session)` from `app.js` and do

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    var token = authenticate.getToken({ _id: req.user._id });
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.json({ success: true, token: token, status: 'You are successfully logged in!' });
});
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33374611)